# Angular - return boolean from function with subscribe block

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, observable, subscribe

Trying to return a boolean value from below function in Angular Service but its not working please help !

```
isActive(id: string): boolean {
        if (!id) {
            return false;
        }
        let userActive = false;
        this.getUsers().subscribe(ActiveUsers => {
            const user = ActiveUsers.find(
                p => p.id === id
            );
            userActive = user ? true : false;
            return userActive;
        });
    }
```

async `getUsers` function (gets its `users` from an API) :

```
getUsers(): Observable<user[]> {
        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to create a variable in your component and store the value there. Then you can use it whenever you need it. I dont know if getUsers is async, so keep that in mind.

```
isActive(id: string): boolean {
        if (!id) {
            this.isActiveValue = false;
        }
        let userActive = false;
        this.getUsers().subscribe(ActiveUsers => {
            const user = ActiveUsers.find(
                p => p.id === id
            );
            userActive = user ? true : false;
            this.isActiveValue = userActive;
        });
    }
```

EDIT:
Ok, then you should keep something in mind. If you have a method that has an observable, then it should return another observable or nothing, just to keep things consistent. Try this:

```
isActive(id: string): Observable<boolean> {
        var subject = new Subject<boolean>();        
        let userActive: boolean = false;
        this.getUsers().subscribe(ActiveUsers => {
            const user = ActiveUsers.find(
                p => p.id === id
            );
            userActive = user ? true : false;
            subject.next(userActive);
        });
        return subject.asObservable();
    }
```

Usage:

```
isActive(id).subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: forgot to mention , `isActive` is a function in Angular service.

Comment: also , `getUsers` is async, gets its data from an API.

Comment: The problem I see with this is that it creates a subscription but never unsubscribes. If isActive is run multiple times it would present as a resource leak. I'm thinking it would be better to call `pipe(map(...))`

Comment: @Ronny: Thanks for your reply. However, I am new to Angular , could you please provide me a brief explanation of why to use a `Subject` in this case and use of `next` and `asObservable` functions. Appreciate your help , thank you

Comment: @AndrewShepherd: could you please provide an implementation with pipe? Also, service function `isActive` will be called from a component where I can unsubscribe, so will it still be an issue if I use method described by @Ronny ?

Comment: Sure. Subjects are a special type of observables, the main difference is that they are multicast, meaning that they keep a registry of all the observers that are subscribed to it, and notifies them when the method next() is called. So think of next() as a way of letting know the subscribers that the value has changed.
The idea of using asObservable() is to prevent the observer side to call the next() method, thus modifying the value. 
And @AndrewShepherd is correct, you should make sure to unsubscribe from the subscription once you no longer need it.

Comment: you guys are Amazing !

Answer (score 1):

Because this is invoking an observable (which is asynchronous), you would need to return an observable or a promise.

Returning an observable:

```
isActive(id: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.getUsers()
        .pipe(
            map(
                activeUsers =>
                    !!(activeUsers.find(p => p.id == id))
            )
        );
    }
```

Usage:

```
isActive(id).subscribe(result => console.log(result))
```

If I wanted a promise, I would start with this code and add some more:

```
isActive(id: string): Promise<boolean> {

    const isActiveObservable = this.getUsers()
        .pipe(
            map(
                activeUsers =>
                    !!(activeUsers.find(p => p.id == id))
            )
        );
    };
    return new Promise<boolean>(
        (resolve, reject) {
            let subscription = isActiveObservable 
                .subscribe({
                    next: isActive => {
                        subscription.unsubscribe();
                        resolve(isActive);
                    },
                    error: e => reject(e) 
                }
            );
        } 
    );
}
```

Usage:

```
isActive(id).then(userIsActive => console.log(userIsActive));
```

Or using the `async` keyword:

```
let userIsActive:boolean = await isActive(id);
console.log(userIsActive)
```

Comment: Thanks. Just want to understand if there is any benefit using this approach compared to using Subject described in answer from @Ronny ?